# Creating multiple password protected shares in Samba

Tags: 13.04, windows, password, samba, shared-folders

So I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 onto a small home server build, and now I'm in a situation I can't quite figure out. I have 2x2TB hard drives (not in RAID) that I'm using for backups. Basically what I'm trying to do is have four folders in one of the drives and share each folder. Also, I'd like to share them with a password so that when they map the folder as a network drive in Windows, only they can access it. However, my user account in Ubuntu will only allow me to use my account for one password protected share in Samba. Does anyone know how I can use Samba or something similar so that I can use one Ubuntu/Samba user but on multiple shares? I'm not very familiar with Linux systems in general, but I have at least a grasp on some of the basic concepts, so the simpler the explanation the better. Thanks ahead. :)

Comment: In general, you can configure samba using the config files in `/etc/samba` directory. See also here: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/samba-fileserver.html